# How to human-labor-efficiently pass all the present and future member function call to its member data object

Tags: c++, templates, macros

I am not very great at writing, so would like to start with a pseudo code:

```
class Wrapper {
public:
  AnyType Foo(std::uint64_t unique_id, Args&&... args) {
     return worker_map[id]->Foo(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
  }
  AnotherType Bar(std::uint64_t unique_id, Args&&... args) {
     return worker_map[id]->Bar(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
  }
private:
  std::unordered_map<std::uint64_t, std::unique_ptr<Worker>> worker_map;
};

class Worker {
public:
 AnyType Foo(<some arguments>);
 AnotherType Bar(<another arguments>);
 // many more methods
};
```

Basically, any public member function of `Wrapper` chooses the right `Worker` object from the map, using the `unique_id` parameter, and forward the rest of arguments to call `Worker`'s member function with the same name (`Foo` and `Bar` in this example).

The thing is there are already many methods of `Worker`, and we are still adding/modifying/removing those.

Is there a way to templatize the name of methods as the name is shared by `Wrapper` and `Worker`?

Comment: Why not just have Wrapper return a reference to the Worker, then you can call any public methods you want?

Comment: It looks like some reflection things... If you want a wrapper to proxy all methods, you have to write them out explicitly

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions and comments!